# JSON в JS-объект

Tags: javascript, json

Помогите, пожалуйста!
Есть задание на обучающей платформе: Написать код, который будет преобразовывать JSON в JS-объект и выводить его в консоль.
Не понимаю, как использовать forEach.
Буду очень признательна)

JSON:

```json
{
 "list": [
  {
   "name": "Petr",
   "age": "20",
   "prof": "mechanic"
  },
  {
   "name": "Vova",
   "age": "60",
   "prof": "pilot"
  }
 ]
}
```

JS-объект:

```js
{list: [
    { name: 'Petr', age: 20, prof: 'mechanic' },
    { name: 'Vova', age: 60, prof: 'pilot' },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Зачем здесь forEach? Визуально и то и то одно и то же...

Comment: `JSON.parse()` есть для преобразования из строки.

Comment: То есть forEach подходит только для XML? Не для JSON?

Comment: forEach это цикл, перебор массива.. причем тут одно к другому)

Comment: `JSON` - это в общем-то "JavaScript Object Notation", то есть прямо вот родной `JS` формат. У вас есть строка и её нужно в JS объекты преобразовать? Непонятно, при чём тут `forEach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const item = `{
 "list": [
  {
   "name": "Petr",
   "age": 20,
   "prof": "mechanic"
  },
  {
   "name": "Vova",
   "age": 60,
   "prof": "pilot"
  }
 ]
}`

JSON.parse(item).list.forEach(obj => console.log(obj));
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

JSON - это строка (String). Поэтому через forEach (принадлежит типу Array, а не String) его перебрать вообще нельзя. (Теоретически можно, но зачем стрелять себе в ногу?)

Используй JSON.parse(string) - преобразовывает **валидную** json строку в js object.

```js
const json = `{
 "list": [
  {
   "name": "Petr",
   "age": "20",
   "prof": "mechanic"
  },
  {
   "name": "Vova",
   "age": "60",
   "prof": "pilot"
  }
 ]
}`;

const jsObjects = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(jsObjects);
jsObjects.list.push({"name": "TEST", "age": 7, "prof": "..."});
console.log(jsObjects);
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли!